# Proof $\Vert Ux \Vert_2 = \Vert x\Vert_2$ for unitary $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, proof-explanation, matrix-decomposition

The statement

$\Vert Ux \Vert_2 = \Vert x\Vert_2$ for unitary $U$

is part of a proof that the 2-norm of a matrix $A=UDV^\top$ yields its largest singular value. It's not immediately clear to me *why* this is the case and the whole statement is simply labelled "matrix fact", so I'm not even sure how to search for it.

Why *does* above statement hold?

Comment: $\langle x,x\rangle = \langle U^TUx,x\rangle = \langle Ux,Ux\rangle$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the columns of $U$ form an orthonormal basis.

So, if $x=[x_1,x_2,\dots x_n]^T$ and $U=[u_1,u_2,\dots, u_n]$ (here $u_i$ are **columns**) then

$$\langle Ux, Ux\rangle = \left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i u_i, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i u_i\right\rangle = \sum_{i,j=1}^n\left\langle x_i u_i, x_ju_j\right\rangle$$

Now use the fact that if $i\neq j$, then $\langle u_i, u_j\rangle = 0$ and you get

$$\langle Ux, Ux\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n\langle x_iu_i, x_iu_i\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\langle u_i, u_i\rangle$$

And of course, since $\langle u_i, u_i\rangle = 1$, you get

$$\|Ux\|_2^2 = \langle Ux, Ux\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 = \|x\|_2^2$$

Comment: Good proof. Personal opinion, seems like a little bit of overkill on the details.

Comment: -1: this makes an arbitrary assumption about what properties of a unitary to use. For that matter, one could have started with $\|Ux\|=\|x\|$.

Answer (score 1):

Unitaries are precisely the matrices that satisfy  $\|Ux\|_2=\|x\|_2$ for all $x $. It is not hard to show that the following statements are equivalent:

- $\|Ux\|_2=\|x\|_2$ for all $x $
- $\langle Ux,Uy\rangle =\langle x,y\rangle $ for all $x,y $
- $U^*U=I_n $
- $UU^*=I_n $
- The rows of $U $ are orthonormal
- The columns of $U $ are orthonormal

Comment: i don't see how this is an answer to OP's question.

Comment: @5xum: Your answer assumes that a unitary matrix has orthonormal columns. One can take that as a definition of unitary. Or one can define (and this is more general, as it extends to infinite dimension) a unitary as a (surjective) isometry, that is a matrix that satisfies $\|Ux\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$. The point is that all possible definitons are equivalent, which is precisely what my answer states.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $||Ux||_2=||x||_2$ consider the square of the left side then you get that $||Ux||_2^2=\langle Ux, Ux \rangle = \langle UU^*x,x \rangle = \langle x,x \rangle = ||x||_2^2$ taking square roots you have the result. The second equality follows from the fact that U has an adjoint and it is a left/right inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $U$ is a complex $n \times n$ matrix such that $U^* U = I$.  If $x \in \mathbb C^n$ then
$$
\|Ux \|_2^2 = (Ux)^* Ux = x^* U^* U x = x^* x = \|x\|_2^2.
$$

Comment: Hmmmm the OP said unitary... not orthogonal.

Comment: @AlecDiaz-Arias Good point, I adjusted my answer.